# What can I do to discourage subjective downvoting on my question?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

The question here ([How can I make Windows Server 2012 R2 like Windows 8.1?](https://superuser.com/questions/664874/how-can-i-make-windows-server-2012-r2-like-windows-8-1)) is being downvoted by several people because they don't think it is a good idea, although it is a clear question. What can I do to get users to provide an objective answer instead of just looking at the subjective nature?

A little history behind the question:

- I have a laptop with a custom install of Windows 7. I wanted to put Windows 8.1 onto it, but it costs $200 (too expensive). Since I am a student, I am entitled to a free license to Windows Server 2008 and higher and $80 for Windows 8.1. I went with the former and installed it dual-boot on my laptop.
- However, I encountered several problems post installation that I would like to fix, so I posted that question.
- Many people think that it is a bad idea to run Windows Server on a laptop (although it is possible due to the battery meter and power plans available), but I want an objective answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the downvoting comes from the fact that the core problem of the question appears to be a financial problem, not a technical one, and *nobody here is interested in solving other people's financial problems*. People see it as "He's being cheap, and that's why he has this problem" and think "He should just stop being cheap".

If you want to avoid that, actually break down the question:

> How do I access the Windows 8 Store on Windows Server 2012R2?

or

> How do I log into Windows Server 2012 with a Microsoft Account instead of a local account?

are much more likely to get straightforward answers than

> How do I make Windows Server 2012 into Windows 8?